# Images aren't loading in desired order

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, load

I have assigned a div id to my images with the intention of loading them in a specific order. However, he image I am trying to load first (pocket2.png) isn't. Any ideas why? The website is here http://edharrisondesign.com/pocketpictograms/.

Thanks in advance!

```
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

        $(".preload").each(loadImages);

            function loadImages (i, elem) {

                var numItems = $('.preload').length;
                for (var i = 0; i < numItems; i++) {

                    $("#img" + i).each(function(){
                        var thisSource = $(this).data('src');
                        $(this).html('<img src="' + thisSource + '" alt=""/>');
                    });
                }

        } //<end loadImages function>

    });
```

Comment: explain what you expect to happen. Code has too many loops in it. Will replace html many many times for each one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The images are all loading asynchronously which means they come in whichever order they finished first, most likely the smallest images first. I wouldn't really worry about the order in which they're loading, it will make little difference on a decent connection.

If you really wanted to optimise your image loading you should have a single giant image containing all images and split it up using CSS or javascript. This means there would only be a single request to the server instead of `numItems` requests.

Comment: Good idea. I think thats a sprite? I haven't used that method before but I will give it a shoot. Nice one Tyriar

Comment: @EdHarrison It's called a spritesheet or a texture atlas (there is a difference, not 100% sure what).